# xamarin.forms.maps native support for bing maps v8

Tags: xaml, xamarin, bing-maps

Are there plans by the xamarin team to make the FormsMaps natively support bing maps v8 api on all platforms?  I'm starting a new development project and am considering xamarin FormsMaps as a core code base, but I need to use the new Bing Maps V8 APIs for ios, android, uwa, and wp.

In looking at the forms.map documentation on xamarin, it appears to only support google maps APIs and requires google map api keys.  I understand that the windows phone will automatically use bing maps natively and that you could force the other platforms to register and use bing maps. What I'm asking is if there are plans to be able to decide which mapping api you want to use for the CPL and have it apply natively to IOS, Android, WP8 and UWP?  Or will this always be a manual process?

I'm especially curious about this, given that Microsoft now owns Xamarin.  Does anyone know the plans for Bing Maps V8 integration and is there any documentation anywhere on this?

Comment: This is not a coding question. You're asking for opinions on research topics

Comment: It was a coding question. I needed to generally know and understand what the options were for coding bing maps v8 controls in xamarin given they don't have native support for bing maps and convert to the native map control.  I didn't need to provide or receive any code, as I just needed to know if was possible, and generally the approach for doing so in Xamarin.  Thanks for the feedback on how to ask questions on StackOverflow, though ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad to see you are interested in using V8 in your mobile app. Many have used the Bing Maps web controls in mobile apps before. Note that Xamarin wraps native API's and uses what ever the default maps are on the device. V8 is a web control, so it is unlikely that the Xamarin team will wrap the V8 web control. You can however use V8 in your Xamarin app by hosting it in a web browser/view control. https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/HybridWebView You then create the mapping functionality you need using JavaScript and then display it in the webview control. You can also connect your native code to JavaScript by injecting JavaScript commands into the webview.

It is possible that Xamarin may use Bing Maps in the future. If it does, it would do so using a native control and not a web control.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer.  I appreciate it.